# force a page using https c#, got error this web page has a redirect loop

Tags: c#, http, redirect, https

I have been trying to do http redirect to https for couple of days, any help would be appreciated! I host my website in a Shared Hosting Environments, I am not allowed to change anything in IIS.

Here's the code in c# login page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("http://") != -1)
    {
        string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "https://");
        //Response.Write(redirectUrl);
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }      
}
```

The error I got is "This web page has a redirect loop". I also tried to do the redirect in web.config file, but having the same error. Is there anyway to force a page using https?

Comment: If you are behind a load balancer type service I believe you need to make sure the `X-Forwarded-For` header is passed through.

Comment: hi asawyer,  any example how I can pass X-Forwarded-For header?

Comment: You can't touch IIS but how about the hosting enviroment. Is it a load balancer? You give no details.  The problem is that the browser talks to the load balance server with HTTPS but the load balancer talks to IIS internally on HTTP port 80. You may be perfectly ok, but the application has no way of knowing or enforcing this. The solution is to configure the balance software to pass the orignial request's http/https value with the `x-forwarded-proto` (not -for, sorry) header, and check that in your application instead, with the `Request.Headers` collection.

Comment: sorry asawyer, I host the website on 123 reg share hosting, the only thing I can control is using ftp to upload files. Is there anyway I can do it in c# or a web.config file? thank you very much

Comment: Send an email and ask them to start using `x-forwarded-proto` Otherwise I don't know what to tell you. Find a better host?

Answer (score -1):

You can ask directly if you are in HTTPS by doing this

```
if(Request.IsSecureConnection)
```

I use this to redirect to my login in HTTPS:

```
if(!IsPostBack){
    if(!Request.IsSecureConnection)
      Response.Redirect("https://" & Request.Url.Host & "/Login.aspx")

......
......
....
...
}
```

Comment: hey Luis, I've just tried ur code, but still gave me the same error.

Comment: This web page has a redirect loop

Comment: This works fine for me, it only redirects if its not a secure Connection, i dont see why you could get this error..

Comment: I know, it makes no sense, it drive me mad. the page will redirect to https//:XXXX/login.aspx, and still show "This web page has a redirect loop".  but thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: @user2055026 Maybe this will help clear up your confusion. http://i.imgur.com/gud66xg.png

Comment: thanks asawye, so there's no way to redirect http to https by coding in share hosting as when individual IIS only can receive http requests?

Comment: @user2055026 The original request from the user is gone. You have to forward the original protocol with the header I mentioned previously. Without that information there is no way for IIS to make any decision.  What our company did was insure that the balancer enviroment enforced HTTPS with it's rules and made a promise to the application that running in HTTP is ok, because the front end communcication is secure.